# How to get all messages sent to my POP3/IMAP server in c#

Tags: c#, imap, pop3, mailkit

I'm trying to figure out how to get all messages sent to my POP3/IMAP server. Right now I'm able to get all messages sent to one user in my POP3 server. I'm using MailKit. But I want to listen to the whole server.

```
        using (var client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
            client.Connect("mail.bar.info", 110, false);
            client.Authenticate("foo@bar.info", "test");

            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
            {
                var message = client.GetMessage(i);
                Console.WriteLine("Mail: {0}", message.Subject);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

Comment: I looked at the Mailkit documentation and I don't think there's a way to do it. Aside from ethical concerns of you inspecting everyone's mail, can you configure your server to forward or copy all received messages  to another mailbox that you have access to?

Comment: If it's your server, you can just examine mail on the server. Most use one file per message, or one file per mailbox. Some use a database, but they're all searchable if you have the right permissions.

Comment: The most important thing for me is to notify the user when they receive a new message. Is there a way to this kind of thing? @Cᴏʀʏ

Comment: It would be better if you inserted a server side component into the SMTP reception path that sent a notification to your user, rather than trying to consume it client side.